# Copy one type of List<> into another type of List<>

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, asp.net-core

For some reason, i need to copy only view details from one list into another list.

```
public class c1
{
public string id{get;set;}
public string firstname{get;set;}
public string lastname{get;set;}
public string category{get;set;}
public string gender{get;set;}
}

public class c2
{
public string id{get;set;}
public string firstname{get;set;}
}
```

Here, in runtime, I will get all the details for the c1 class, and I need to store only 2parameters to store into c2.
How can i achieve this?
I tried below, but its not working!!

```
dynamic d=from a in c1 
      select new   
      {
       a.id,
       a.firstname
      };

List<c2> c2list=d;
```

Comment: continution comment to above question: I dont want to use foreach loop.!

Comment: check my answer below. It will do what you want without using an explicit foreach loop

Comment: @Vihasi `select` uses a `foreach` loop - you just don't see it.

Comment: After creating both Lists, have you tried `List<string> lstNew = listold.GetRange(0, 2);` ? You could try, it could help you add parameters from one list to another. Ref: [List<T>.GetRange(Int32, Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.getrange?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 3):

Use ToList method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=net-6.0

```
List<c2> list2 = (from a in c1 
                  select new c2  
                  {
                      a.id,
                      a.firstname
                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: No need for `dynamic` here. Can simply use `c2`

Comment: FYI @Vihasi, the key here is not the `ToList`, but the `new c2` in the `select`. You can't simply use `dynamic` to convert an anonymous type into a named type just because they have the same properties.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example:

```
void Main()
{
    List<c1> c1List = new List<c1>();
    List<c2> c2List = new List<c2>();
    
    c1 example1 = new c1 {
        category = "some category",
        firstname = "John",
        gender = "some gender",
        id = "1",
        lastname = "Smith",
    };
    
    c1List.Add(example1);

    c2List.AddRange(c1List.Select(x => new c2 {
        firstname = x.firstname,
        id = x.id
    }));
    

    
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here

public class c1
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
}

public class c2
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
}
```

This outputs them into a list as follows:

[image]